# Load a DateTime array into ListBox?

Tags: c#, arrays, datetime, settings.settings

How can I save a Properties.Settings.Default.Array using DateTime format (with just the time)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, i found this

Add a setting, type select browse and find System.Collection.ArrayList.

for saving the values

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.test == null)
   Properties.Settings.Default.test = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
Properties.Settings.Default.test.Add(new DateTime(2009, 1, 1));
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

for retrieveing the values

```
System.Collections.ArrayList list = Properties.Settings.Default.test;
for (int iDate = 0; iDate < list.Count; iDate++)
{
   DateTime dateValue = (DateTime)list[iDate];
}
```

Have a look at [Using Settings in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: Saving works, but how can I get the Listbox to load the values from the settings?